# terraform create elb instead of alb

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I use a terraform script to build up the infrastructure.
For nginx controller I use kubernetes_addons.
for the first try I use the NLB sample code to build the load balancer and it works well.

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "${scheme}"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "${internal}"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-node-labels: kubernetes.io/os=linux
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
      # Enable proxy protocol
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: "true"
      # Specify whether the DigitalOcean Load Balancer should pass encrypted data to backend droplets
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough: "true"
```

However I do not need a nlb, I need a ALB in case of OIDC authorization to AbzureAD. For this I canged the controller to:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "${scheme}"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-idp-oidc: >-
        {"secretName":"xxx","issuer":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/v2.0","authorizationEndpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize","tokenEndpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token","userInfoEndpoint":"https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo"}
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-on-unauthenticated-request: authenticate
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-scope: openid
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-timeout: '604800'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: oidc
```

The subnets are marked with tags to use the alb.
I call this loadbalancer creation with:

```
  ingress_nginx_helm_config = {
    values = [templatefile("${path.module}/templates/nginx_values.yaml", {
      internal = "false",
      scheme   = "internet-facing",
    })]
    namespace         = "nginx",
    create_namespace  = true
    dependency_update = true
  }
```

But finaly after terraform is ready I have a elb not an alb. Any Idea what I miss here?
As I understand, the service.beta.kubernetes.io is just for nlb definition.

Comment: Have you installed the `aws-load-balancer-controller` add-on? In EKS ALB is used to for ingress, not for service of type load balancer. See docs here: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/

Comment: This issue seems to be extrinsic to the Terraform config, and completely within the Kubernetes annotations and controller behavior.